# use google+ api oauth2 service error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have followed the document(https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest) setup my business network , and use my own google accounts.
when I access http://localhost:3000/auth/google , then operated `allow` action, got error after minutes waiting.

error as follows:

```
   {
　　"error":{
　　　　"statusCode":500,
　　　　"name":"InternalOAuthError",
　　　　"message":"Failed to obtain access token",
　　　　"oauthError":{
　　　　　　"code":"ECONNREFUSED",
　　　　　　"errno":"ECONNREFUSED",
　　　　　　"syscall":"connect",
　　　　　　"address":"172.217.24.13",
　　　　　　"port":443
　　　　},
　　　　"stack":"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.217.24.13:443
at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/home/composer/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:379:17)
at /home/composer/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45
at /home/composer/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:191:18
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/composer/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:162:5)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)"
　　}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its trying to contact `accounts.google.com` with the IP address 172.217.24.13.

https://ipinfo.io/172.217.24.13

That is almost certainly some kind of local networking problem. Are you in an office with a firewall, or a proxy enabled? Because of this, it cannot go to the next step which is to redirect to http://localhost:3000/explorer

Maybe you need HTTPS_PROXY set for https requests. AFAIK, it may be either a complete URL or a “host[:port]” etc.